# Keeping track of an image type with Django's FileField

Tags: python, django, upload, python-imaging-library

My model has a `FileField` that accepts images. I validate them with Pillow and enforce an image format, but I'd also like to save the image file with its appropriate extension. For example, if I upload a JPEG image named `foo.gif`, I'd like to save it as `000.jpg`, where the numbers are another field in the model.

Where do I store the image format so that I can reuse it later in my `upload_to` callable to generate an upload path?

```
class ImageField(models.FileField):
    default_error_messages = {
        'invalid_image': "Upload a valid image. The file you uploaded was either not an image or a corrupted image.",
        'invalid_format': "Upload an image in a valid format. The supported formats are JPEG and PNG.",
    }

    def to_python(self, data):
        f = super(ImageField, self).to_python(data)

        if f is None:
            return None

        if hasattr(data, 'temporary_file_path'):
            file = data.temporary_file_path()
        elif hasattr(data, 'read'):
            file = BytesIO(data.read())
        else:
            file = BytesIO(data['content'])

        try:
            image = Image.open(file)
            image.verify()

            if image.format not in {'PNG', 'JPEG'}:
                raise ValidationError(self.error_messages['invalid_format'], code='invalid_format')
        except Exception:
            raise ValidationError(self.error_messages['invalid_image'], code='invalid_image')

        if hasattr(f, 'seek') and callable(f.seek):
            f.seek(0)

        return f

class Image(models.Model):
    number = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    image = ImageField(upload_to=self.upload_path)

    def upload_path(self, instance, upload_filename):
        return ???
```

Comment: First of all, why are you using `FileField`, and not `ImageField` which exists in Django? See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ImageField

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the code fragment you've pasted above comes from *django forms*. Note, that Django has two kinds of field classes: **Model** fields and **Form** fields. Their names are often the same, but the implementation and purpose is totally different. In your example you are trying to use code copied from *form* field in a custom *model* field.

The code which is really interesting for you is here: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/files/images.py - this is the fragment where dimensions of the image are extracted. Mixin class **`ImageFile`** is then used here: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/files.py in **`ImageFieldFile`**. The latter is then used as an attribute class in **`ImageField`** model field class.

So, all you need is:

1. Copy `django/core/files/images.py` and modify it to extract not only dimensions but also file type (say, you name this mixin `ImageFileWithType`).
2. Override `ImageFieldFile` by providing your custom mixin;
3. Override `ImageField` class, replacing the attribute class in it.

```py
from your_custom_fields_module import ImageFileWithType
from django.db.models.fields import ImageFieldFile, ImageField


class ImageFieldFileWithType(ImageFileWithType, ImageFieldFile):
    """As `ImageFileWithType` mixin is at the beginning,
    it overrides default mixin"""
    pass


class ImageFieldWithType(ImageField):
    attr_class = ImageFieldFileWithType
```

Then just use this model field in your model! Note that if you are using South migrations, you will need special care for handling custom model fields.

Hope, this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Really, it doesn't seem like you even need to use Pillow from what I can tell (unless there's more to the project you're not posting). All you need is to define a [storage system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/custom-file-storage/) and then--on retrieval--access the `FileField`'s [`FieldFile` class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile). I'd recommend this method since 99% of the time information on a file and it's format is found by either using the file object itself, determining the information from it's filename, or (in some rare cases) doing some command-line magic with `subprocess`.

In any case, here's a Storage example:

```
from django.core.files.storage import Storage

class MyStorage(Storage):
    ...
    def get_valid_name(name):
        return name.replace('gif', 'jpg')
    ...
```

That's where you might be a little confused. Django has it's own storage engine that will automatically write the files to your `MEDIA_ROOT` directory. Thus, your code snippet

```
def upload_path(self, instance, upload_filename):
    return ???
```

is redundant (if you define your own Storage, that is ;) ) Does it make more sense now? **django.core.files.storage.Storage is there to help you.**

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm explaining my problem well enough. Even with a storage system, how would I access the image file's type without looking at the extension? Just pretend that the image that was uploaded has a filename of just `image` and I need to figure out if it's a JPG, PNG, and if it's actually an image. Once that's done, I can determine its full filename.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I see. Sorry for not understanding.

Pillow provides an [Image Class](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image) that contains information on an image. [`Image.format`](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.format) may be the property you want.

I even did a little test of my own to see if extension mattered:

```
user@host:~/Images$ cp myimage.jpg myimage.gif
user@host:~/Images$ cp myimage.jpg myimage.txt  # Extreme test!
user@host:~/Images$ python
Python 2.7.4 (default, Apr 19 2013, 18:28:01) 
[GCC 4.7.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> im = Image.open('/home/user/Images/myimage.jpg')
>>> im.format
'JPEG'
>>> im = Image.open('/home/user/Images/myimage.gif')
>>> im.format
'JPEG'
```

Nope, doesn't matter. Looks good! **☺**

Comment: Yep, if you look at my code, you can see that I'm validating the image using this property. It looks like Django's `ImageFileField` actually computes width and height for every image and caches the result in-memory, not in the database, so I'm going to have to just do this in a form.